# How to change /etc/hosts make it can visit multi folder under /var/www/html

Tags: centos, hosts

I have a local centos pc , I use it as my online wordpress 's backup , mean it also have a wordpress site which can only visit from local  .

here is my current /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
:1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
127.0.0.1  wordpress
192.168.3.116 wordpress
```

and in my pc 's  /var/www/html , now have two folders :   wordpress   and  javascripts

under this setting , I can visit wordpress by type :

```
http://192.168.3.116
```

for the folder javascripts , it is where I want to save some files while I learn javascripts .

but now the question is , how can I visit javascripts folder , since http://192.168.3.116 already assign to wordpress

could anyone tell me how to change /etc/hosts to finish it

Answer (score 0):

set **192.168.3.116 javascripts** and follow apache documentation for virtualhosts